# How to check if string contains a substring in dash or ash?

Tags: shell-script, shell, grep, string

Here is what I am tring:

```
#!/bin/sh
contains() {
    if $(echo $1 | grep -c $2) ; then
        echo "0" # contains
    else
        echo "1" # not contains
    fi
}

myString=$1
mySubsting=$2

contains $myString '$mySubsting'
```

Here is an example of execution:

```
# sh ./myScript abcdef bc
./myTest: line 3: 0: command not found
1
```

**EDITED:**

**Original question was: How to check if string contains a substring in Bourne Shell?**

Here is what I am tring:

```
  #!/bin/sh
  if echo $1 | grep -q $2
  then
    echo "0"
  else
    echo "1"
  fi
```

Here is an example of execution:

```
$ sh ./myTest "$(systemctl status ntp)" "Active: active"
grep: active: No such file or directory
1
```

How to properly check if one string contains another?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Bourne shell had a construct for that. That's the same as in modern `sh` (which seems more like what you're using, the Bourne shell had no support for `$(...)`; if it was the Bourne shell, you'd get a different error):

```
case $1 in
  *"$2"*) printf '"%s" is in "%s"\n' "$2" "$1"
esac
```

If you wanted to use `grep`, that would be:

```
if printf '%s\n' "$1" | grep -Fqe "$2"; then
  printf '"%s" is in "%s"\n' "$2" "$1"
fi
```

Or

```
if grep -Fqe "$2" << EOF
$1
EOF
then
  printf '"%s" is in "%s"\n' "$2" "$1"
fi
```

But that would only work properly if `$2` contained no newline character.

In any case, you need quotes around most of those parameter expansion. The only place where it's not needed is in that `case $1` above, but even then `case "$1"` wouldn't harm.

A few notes on your code:

1. [You can't use `echo` for arbitrary strings](/q/65803). Here, depending on the `echo` implementation, it would fail for values of `$1` like `-n` or `foo\bar`.
2. [Leaving a parameter expansion unquoted has a very special meaning in shells](/q/171346). You don't want to do that. Try for instance that `grep -c $2` with a value of `$2` like `*` or `root /etc/passwd`.
3. `grep` without `-F` is for regexp matching. You need `-F` for fixed string (substring) search (used to be with `fgrep`), but again if `$2` contains multiple lines, that tells `grep -F` to search for *any* of the content of those lines in the input (`grep -F $'a\nb'` would look for `a` or `b`, not the `$'a\nb'` string).
4. In `grep -c $2`, the content of `$2` would be taken as an option if it started with `-`. You want `grep -c -e "$2"` or `grep -c -- "$2"` to avoid that.
5. You want to use the exit status, not stdout to report boolean conditions. In scripts that's with `exit` (`exit 0` for true, `exit 1` (or any non-zero number, but avoid values greater than 120) for false). For functions, use `return` instead. Though both scripts and functions will return with the status of the last run command.
6. `$(cmd)` *expands* to the output of `cmd` (and undergoes split+glob here because of the missing quotes again) minus the trailing newline characters. So if `cmd` outputs `0\n`, `$(cmd)` expands to `0`. So running `$(cmd)` tries to run the command called `0`. If you want to convert the output of `cmd` to an exit status (so it can be used as a boolean), you'd need `(exit "$(cmd)")`. That starts a subshell that exits with the output of `cmd` as its exit code).
7. `grep -c` counts the number of occurrences. Here you don't need to have the full count, you only need to know if it's found at all (if there's at least one match). For that `grep -q` is more efficient as it stops searching after it found one. For ancient `grep` implementations that don't support the (standard) `-q` option, you can use `fgrep -le "$2" > /dev/null`. With `-l`, `fgrep` also stops upon the first match, but outputs the file name (which we discard here by redirecting the output to `/dev/null`).

Comment: @Alexandr, see edit.

Comment: Stéphane Chazelas, wow, so much information. I am novice to linux scripting so I haven't known those things. Thank you for explanation one more time. It is just amazing

Answer (score 9):

A portable (dash,bash,ksh, etc) script containing a function:

```
#!/bin/sh

contains() {  if    [ "$1" ] &&            # Is there a source string.
                    [ "$2" ] &&            # Is there a substring.
                    [ -z "${1##*"$2"*}" ]; # Test substring in source.
              then  echo 0;                # Print a "0" for a match.
              else  echo 1;                # Print a "1" if no match.
              fi;
            }

contains "$1" "$2"
```

Where 0 means "contains" (true value).

which will test as:

```
 $ contains "test a simple line" simpl
 1

 $ contains "One sentence" "No more"
 0
```

Answer (score 1):

bash supports this natively;

```
$ string1="abcmoocow"
$ string2="moo"
$ if [[ $string1 == *$string2* ]]; then echo "Match"; else echo "No Match"; fi
Match
$ string1="abccrowcow"
$ if [[ $string1 == *$string2* ]]; then echo "Match"; else echo "No Match"; fi
No Match
```

also to correct your example; change;

```
if $(echo $1 | grep -c $2) ; then
```

to become:

```
if [ -n "$(echo $1 | grep -c $2)" ]; then
```

(checks if the grep returns any data)

also note it is also possible to work with the exit code;

```
$ echo bob | grep "o" &>/dev/null; echo $?
0
$ echo bob | grep "z" &>/dev/null; echo $?
1
```

Comment: `[[ $string1 == *$string2* ]]` (for substring match) would be `zsh` syntax. In `bash` (or `ksh` where that syntax comes from), you'd need `[[ $string1 == *"$string2"* ]]` instead as otherwise, the content of `$string2` would be taken as a pattern.

Comment: `grep -c` outputs a count of matching lines. When there's no match, that still outputs `0`, so `[ -n "$(...grep -c...)" ]` would always be true (except for the errors possibly incurred by the missing quotes).

Comment: pattern moo would suffice, and yes i should have pruned op's grep to remove "-c".